# The remote name could not be resolved when creating blob Container

Tags: c#, winforms, azure, blob

im trying to store screenshots to cloud with azure but i keep geting this exception:
The remote name could not be resolved:'azuretest.blob.core.windows.net.blob.core.windows.net'

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("screenshots");
container.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you have wrong account name in connection string, you should have:

`AccountName=azuretest`

instead of:

`AccountName=azuretest.blob.core.windows.net`

Answer (score 3):

You've set "blob.core.windows.net" twice. If you use "azuretest.blob.core.windows.net", it should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the "EndpointSuffix" key from the connection string to resolve this issue.

From

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account name>;AccountKey=<accoount key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net​​
```

To

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<account name>;AccountKey=<accoount key>
```

Answer (score 0):

In app settings section just added below settings without extensions like http, https and azuresearch.search.azure.com ...

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="SearchServiceName" value="azuresearch" />
    <add key="SearchServiceApiKey" value="629B1FEC5627AC0D4546B64F1375A634322" />
  </appSettings
```

This is works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue .This exception also throws when azure doesn't found proper internet connection.So,check your internet connection and try again .I hope this may resolve this issue.