# Remote Name Can't Be Resolved accountname.blob.core.windows.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-blob-storage

I have an ASP.NET MVC application that connects to Azure blob storage; locally everything is fine and I can connect to blob storage and access my containers and list blobs, but once deployed I get this error:

> Azure.RequestFailedException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'MyAccountName.blob.core.windows.net'

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this error?
Here is the container code for connecting to the Azure Blob

```
    public ActionResult QuickPhotos()
    {
        string storageConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTIONSTRING"].ConnectionString;
        string containerName = "infoimages";
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(storageConnectionString, containerName);
        List<string> Images = new List<string>();
        foreach (BlobItem item in blobContainerClient.GetBlobs())
        {
            Images.Add("https://azureblob.interstellarseries.com/" + containerName +"/"+item.Name);
        }
        return View(Images);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share your code about connecting to blob storage?

Comment: @PamelaPeng Updated Question with the code, sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have wrong account name in connection string,

you should have:**AccountName=Your Account Name**,

instead of:
**AccountName=Your Account name.blob.core.windows.net**

For more details check with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27019478/the-remote-name-could-not-be-resolved-when-creating-blob-container)